# Перенос элементов при уменьшении окна

Tags: css

Вопрос мой скорее всего вы уже слышали тысячу раз. Так что сразу извиняюсь за свои пробелы в знаниях. К проблеме ...

Сделал сайт на `Wordpress`. После шапки в теле сайта идёт разделение на 2 блока . Слева `слайдер` , справа `меню`.

Далее хотел создать ниже всего этого на всю ширину сайта 4 картинки с ссылками. Проблема в том что как только я создаю эти элементы, они отображаются на ширину слайдера, а не на всю ширину сайта.

Если я прописываю `width` в пикселях, при уменьшении Окна вместо того чтобы переносится вниз, элементы остаются за пределами Окна.

Если я прописываю `width :100%` , то элементы опять располагаются по ширине слайдера , нежели по всей ширине сайта .

Помогите , уже замучился. Не знаю можно ли здесь написать адрес сайта, для наглядности.

Comment: Написать сайт можно, но скорее всего мало кто перейдёт по ссылке. Учитывая описываемую Вами проблему - сначала обратите внимание на  родителя данного элемента, не ограничивает ли он пространство.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Это правда :)))

Comment: Коллеги правы оба раза. Первый раз, что лучше сюда помещать проблемные куски кода. Второй раз в том, что ваши картинки, очевидно, размещаются внутри блока со слайдером. А вы желаете, судя по всему, разместить их ниже после блока с сайдбаром (тот, где меню). Их нужно поместить или в футере (footer), или над ним.

Comment: Как только доберусь до компа сброшу код. Скорее всего родитель и ограничивает . Только как это исправить чтобы все остальное содержимое родителя осталось на местах?

Comment: Да , именно под сайдбаром мне и хотелось бы разместить. Так как в мобильной версии сначала отображается содержимое блока со слайдером , а потом уже меню . Вообщем сброшу Код попозже . Большое спасибо что уделяете время .

Comment: @Mihail, Если тема у вас одна из стандартных, то почти наверняка средняя часть сайта, та, что между хедером и футером обозначена как <div id="content">... Вероятно в самом низу этого блока и надо разместить ваши картинки. Но их бы я тоже забрал в некий блок и присвоил id или class, чтобы легче было потом ориентироваться да и внешний вид настраивать. Сейчас, похоже непосредственным родителем ссылок у вас является блок слайдера.

Comment: Я их где только не пробовал разместить честно говоря . Видимо что-то не так я делаю . Не знаю когда доберусь до компа, напишу адрес сайта , может посмотрите так ? msp62.ru Ещё раз спасибо за то что уделяете своё время

Comment: Картинкам этим присваивал div . И как раз div и пытался задать ширину в пикселях. Но тогда начинает содержимое при сужении экрана уходить за грани Окна .а если в % , то содержимое становится по ширине слайдера

Comment: @Mihail дайте ссылку, как будет возможность. Вывод из этой длинной переписки один - всегда публикуйте в вопросе кусок проблемного кода. Так не будет нужна вся эта переписка, а ошибку можно будет найти в разы быстрее.

Comment: msp62.ru вот ссылка . С вами согласен полностью .

Comment: @Mihail, пардон, а где картинки под слайдером? ))

Comment: Извините , я их удалил) Сайт действующий , не хотелось чтобы клиенты видели эти недоделки.

Answer (score 0):

На вашем сайте такая структура:

```
<div id="main" class="clearfix">
  <div id="inner-wrap">
    <div id="primary">...</div>
    <div id="secondary">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В primary расположен слайдер, в secondary - меню, а ниже, но вероятно всё ещё в блоке inner-wrap следует разместить блок с вашими картинками, ссылками, что там у вас...
Примерно так:

```
<div id="main" class="clearfix">
  <div id="inner-wrap">
    <div id="primary">...</div>
    <div id="secondary">...</div>
    <div id="myimages">ваши картинки</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Разумеется, id для блока можно придумать любой. Осталось разыскать, в каком файле шаблона нужно добавить этот код.

Comment: Единственное что , отображаются теперь эти картинки на всех страницах после контента . Но не факт что это плохо . Я пока ещё не думал об этом

Comment: @Mihail, 2 момента. 1: сайдбары в wordpress бывают разные. В вашем случае, похоже сайдбар расположен снизу. При смене темы, да и при перенастройки этой - сайдбар может оказаться слева или справа. Строго говоря, ваше меню справа - и есть сайдбар. 2: по вордпрессу есть масса сайтов. Можно, например, указать в какой записи, странице или в какой категории записей что-либо должно или не должно отображаться. Но это уже совсем другой вопрос.